# String index out of range: Java

Tags: java, string

> > I'm getting String out of range 
> >     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
> >     5     at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)     at
> >     Lab6.DataSentinelWhile3.main(DataSentinelWhile3.java:24)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence;
        char ch = 'a';
        int ind = 0, upperLetter=0, lowerLetter=0, digits=0, punctuation=0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a sentence (full-stop to terminate):");
        sentence = input.nextLine();
        while(ch != '.') {
            if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
                lowerLetter++;
            else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
                upperLetter++;
            else if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
                digits++;
            else
                punctuation++;

            ind++; //increase the index of the sentence by 1
            ch = sentence.charAt(ind); //extract every character from sentence
        }

        System.out.print("\n\n*****Lexical Analysis of your Sentence*****" + 
        "\nLowercase letters: " + lowerLetter +
        "\nUppercase letters: " + upperLetter +
        "\nDigits: " + digits +
        "\nPunctuation symbols: " + (punctuation+1));
        input.close();
    }
```

Comment: What did you learn when you ran this with the debugger?

Comment: This is counting as punctuation a huge amount of characters which are not punctuation (accented characters for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use forloop when possible, possibility of error reduces by 10 folds:, for while loop:

```
     ind i = 0; 
     while(ind < sentence.length){
        ch = sentence.charAt(ind);
        if(ch == '.') break;
        if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
            lowerLetter++;
        else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
            upperLetter++;
        else if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
            digits++;
        else
            punctuation++;
        ind++;
     }
```

Comment: I am asked to use while loop :(

Comment: @danazzy there, converted the forloop to while loop.

Comment: This answer is correct.  It works well, but it has one feature that I dislike greatly.  One important part of the logic is `ch = sentence.charAt(ind)`, which runs in every case.  But by burying it inside the first `if`, it looks like this is part of the condition, or that its impact is limited to the first `if`.  For readability and maintainability, it would be much better to extract this assignment into its own line, above the `if`, and to write the first  `if` as `if (ch == '.')`

Comment: @DavidWallace :-) Because of the old concise C ways, my habit is to do the assignment and conditional checking in the same line.

Comment: @shnaz yw, no problem :-)

Comment: @Aniket Even when I was a C programmer (about 20 years ago now), that kind of practice was frowned upon.  No matter what language you are programming in, you should always be thinking about readability and maintainability.  Your code should speak to any programmer who looks at it in the future; and it should speak slowly and clearly, and always be understood at first reading.

Answer (score 1):

try this loop

while(ind < sentence.length)
{

}

change this

ch = sentence.charAt(ind);
  ind++;

Comment: @DavidWallace change this

ch = sentence.charAt(ind); ind++;

Answer (score 0):

`while(ch != '.')`

You should set your loop on the string length, if `sentence` doesn't end with a final dot `"."` it doesn't stop.